# Replacing Foreign Characters with English Equivalents in filenames with UNIX Bash Script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to use sed to process a list of filenames and replace every foreign character in the file name with an English equivelent.  E.g.

málaga.txt ->  malaga.txt

My script is the following:

```
    for f in *.txt 
do
    newf=$(echo $f | sed 'y/āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ/aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuüüüüAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUÜÜÜÜ/')
    mv $f $newf
done
```

This currently has no effect on the filenames.  However if I use the same regex to process a text file.  E.g.

```
cat blah.txt | sed 'y/āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ/aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuüüüüAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUÜÜÜÜ/
```

It works perfectly - all foreign characters are substituted with their English equivalents.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is on Mac OsX in a UNIX shell.

Comment: Nice one, but tell me what are foreign characters? ;)

Comment: I mean characters like these: āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ

Comment: A language foreign to you might be native to some else is what I meant. You don't have to explain further. Your questions is pretty clear on what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: I have no recipe how to make it work yet, but this could give you a hint: it seems it doesn't work because those characters are represented by different sets of bytes when echoing/catting a file compared to ls/bash glob expansion. `echo -n 'Ã' | hexdump -C` will give you `c3 83`, when ls'ing a directory with two files named `Ã` and `a` gives you `41 cc 83` for `Ã` for some reason. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PavelGurkov: that's because in HFS+ filenames are stored in NFD: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1235/_index.html

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties

Comment: This could end up effectivly deleting some of your files. If you have a file called a and another file called á your a file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    newf=$(echo $f | iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8 | sed 'y/āáǎàēéěèīíǐìōóǒòūúǔùǖǘǚǜĀÁǍÀĒÉĚÈĪÍǏÌŌÓǑÒŪÚǓÙǕǗǙǛ/aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuüüüüAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUÜÜÜÜ/')
    mv $f $newf
done
```

`iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8` converts the text from utf-8-mac to utf-8, which resolves the precomposed/decomposed problem discussed in the comments by @PavelGurkov and @ninjalj.